# ksh keybind trap

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, ksh

I am trying to follow this code sample

http://www.kornshell.com/examples/keybind

```
# Example from page 98
typeset -A Keytable
trap 'eval "${Keytable[${.sh.edchar}]}"' KEYBD
function keybind # key [action]
{
    typeset key=$(print -f "%q" "$2")
    case $# in
    2)      Keytable[$1]=' .sh.edchar=${.sh.edmode}'"$key"
            ;;
    1)      unset Keytable[$1]
            ;;
    *)      print -u2 "Usage: $0 key [action]"
            return 2 # usage errors return 2 by default
            ;;
    esac
}
```

and this one as well: https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall01/G22.2245-001/syll/lect7.pdf

If I press Ctrl+C the terminal line clears out
pressing Ctrl+L I see the ^L

I'd like to have Ctrl+L bind to the clear command.

How can I setup the KEYBD function above to capture this command and clear the terminal?